# How to check whether API endpoint request is made from AWS lambda or not?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm using NodeJS to create REST APIs for a web app. I want a few endpoints to be triggered only from AWS Lambda functions.

How can I identify whether a request is made from AWS Lambda or not and restrict accordingly?

Comment: When you say you wanted few endpoints to be triggered from AWS functions, do you really have to expose the endpoint for other use case? If not, you can simply invoke that lambda from another lambda without passing through API Gateway

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether there is another way to do it. But you can achieve this way :

- Add a secure key to the AWS Lambda environment variable.
- Whenever you call API from the lambda pass secret key in a request header.
- Check for the request header at receiving end.